# Accessing model attribute from css/less file with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, less

The project I'm working on requires me to adapt the size of the elements on screen according to per-user setting. We're using Twitter bootstrap, so my first idea was to toy with the `@basefont` value, and it seems to do the trick.

However, I don't know how to access the user setting from the `.less` file. I tried using erb with `.less.erb`, but it looks like I don't have access to any code in my application.

Is there a way to get the value I'm looking for from the `.less` file, or - even better - a proper way to do this ?

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

Since I need to get the value at runtime, the way I tried won't work anyway, though I'm still interested on an answer. The only way I see to do what I want is to add a class according to the user setting. Again, I'd be glad to have alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for css3 `transform` (and vendors implementation) property. It does the job, but seems to hit the GPU quite a lot. So still open to other answers. :)